# How to use multiple servers inside single Report

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report where i have to use two servers for accessing two different tables data. For this i use 2 datasets, one for query A in server A, another for query B in Server B.

The result of query A which i used in Server A, has to be passed to Query B which is in Server B. I need to do this without using Linked Servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I i understood this correctly you are just passing paramaters between report from Server A and Server B and since for all the reports we just use SELECT statments or any storedprocedure fetching from diffrent servers should not be a problem and you don't need to create a linked server for that.

If you can post any error you are getting while achiveing this please feel free.

I have also used 3 dataset (3 diffrent servers) for generating report i didn't face any problem in that.